# How to find multiple values using Binary Search in Python

Tags: python, binary-search

I am using a standard binary search algorithm that takes an integer value as an argument, and searches through a list for the integer. However, I want to be able to find the indexes of the location of each integer in the list that matches the search value. What I have so far is:

```
def bin_search(x):
    my_list = [57,68,76,77,82,86,89,89,89,98,100]
    bottom = 0
    top = len(my_list)-1
    found = False
    location = -1
    while(bottom <= top) and not(found):
        middle = int((bottom + top)//2)
        if(my_list[middle] == x):
            location = middle
            found = True
        else:
            if x < my_list[middle]:
                top = middle - 1
            else:
                bottom = middle + 1

    return location

print(bin_search(89))
```

Any help in making this binary search able to find two values would be appreciated!

Comment: post the stack trace. *where* are you getting the error?

Comment: why do you make `location` a list? I bet this is the source of your error.

Comment: Do you need to reinvent the wheel? [The `bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) provides APIs that can directly determine [the left](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) and [right](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) bounds for a given value (or you just go straight to the left and start scanning linearly until you reach the end of the run of identical values).

Comment: I made it a list so that I could store multiple values for the location.

Comment: ok but then you need to deal with it correctly, you can't turn a list into an int.

Comment: First get this working with just finding a single index. Then, add code at the end of the function that (if the value was found—otherwise just return `[-1]` or whatever) builds a list by extending out left and right from that index until the value no longer matches.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I would like to use binary search, as I have little experience with it. Although thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Newoej `bisect` _is_ binary search. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html). (And, while you're at it, notice that the docs link to the source, so if you're not sure how they could have done some particular feature, you can just click and see how they did it.)

Comment: @abarnert I guess my question is how to make the code at the end of the function. I already have it working with one index, and now I'm trying to make it work with multiple, which is why the search doesn't work right now.

Comment: Well, the code right now isn't working. So first go back to working code that finds one value. Then try to write the loop at the end of the function that extends out from that value. Then, if you get stuck on that code, post that code here, rather than code that you know doesn't make sense.

Comment: @abarnert The code now works for one index.

Comment: @Julien Sorry I forgot to delete the error, the code works properly right now. However, there are multiple indexes that have the value that I am searching for, so I am trying to create a binary search that is able to return the location of all items that match the search value.

Comment: OK, so now try to write the code that takes that one location, and builds a list out of it by scanning (linearly, or by bisecting again, but try linear first because it's simpler) to the lowest and highest indices that match from there. If you get stuck, we can help you. But now you're just asking us to write your code.

Comment: @abarnert Okay thanks, I will try that and update my question if I get stuck.

Comment: I've got it now, thanks all for your help!

Comment: Since you have it now, please either remove your question or post the code you came up with in the answer section (yes, you can answer your own question).

Answer (score 0):

Adding in this code at the end of the binary search will provide the user with the index of the first and last occurrence of the value that is being searched for (x in this case). The user can then use the indexes to find the range of indexes that matches the searched item, since they know the indexes of the first and last occurrence of the searched item.

```
# Index of last occurrence
location2 = -1
# Index of first occurrence
location3 = -1

# Finds last index that matches x
for I in range(len(my_list)):
    if my_list[I] == x:
        location2 = I
# Finds first index that matches x
for I in range(len(my_list)):
    if my_list[I] == x:
        location3 = I
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

What comes to mind would be to perform the binary search twice: once on the list in sorted order and another time on the list sorted in reverse order.

Then knowing the length of the list, you could obtain the first and last index for the element that you are looking for.

From this [article](https://stackabuse.com/search-algorithms-in-python/):

> One drawback of binary search is that if there are multiple occurrences of an element in the array, it does not return the index of the first element, but rather the index of the element closest to the middle

What you could do is to [remove duplicates from the list and remember the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569966/remove-duplicates-in-python-list-but-remember-the-index), then perform binary search.

Answer (score 0):

Well this can be done in python easily,
By checking the first occurrence to target and removing the value from the list if it matches.
And continuing the search...

```
print("Binary Search!")
my_arr =[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
my_arr.append(4)
print(my_arr)
target = 4
low = 0
high = len(my_arr)-1
while(low<=high):
    mid = (low+high)//2
    if my_arr[mid]==target:
        print("found target",my_arr[mid],mid)
        my_arr.remove(my_arr[mid])
    elif my_arr[mid]>target:
        high =mid-1
    else:
        low = mid +1
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is a binary search algorithm that has a constant runtime. The function makes use of a `while` loop to run through the list of variables or values in the list and exit when the condition is reached but also stop running and return a `None` value when the target is not found.

```
def binarySerach(list, target):
    first = 0
    last = len(list) -1  #get size of list
    
    while first <= last:
        midpoint = (first + last) // 2 # rounds to whole number
        if list[midpoint] == target:
            return midpoint
        elif list[midpoint] < target:
            first = midpoint + 1
        else:
            last = midpoint - 1 
   return None

def verify(index):
    if index is not None:
        print("Target found at index: ", index)
    else:
        print("Target not found in list")
    

my_list = [57,68,76,77,82,86,89,89,89,98,100]
result = binarySerach(my_list,89)
verify(result)
```